# Fetch specific record value from a table in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to dynamically calculate the **% Change** of the prices in a table, where each price will be compared with the first price (Price in the first record, ordered by date). There is a date filter, so the first record being displayed will change accordingly. Date column values are unique.

Assume the user applies a filter for date BETWEEN '15-APR-2021' AND '30-APR-2021'. Then the expected '% Change' column would look like:

[image: Example]

For this example, I had to hardcode the starting price in the calculation:

> % Change = (('table1'[price]/**3218.95**) -1)*100

I tried the below, but it doesn't return a static value of 3218.95. Instead, it re-calculates it at record level rather filtered table level as we see in the above screenshot :

```
first_date = (MIN(table1[Date]))
first_price = LOOKUPVALUE('table1'[price],table1[Date],'table1'[first_date])
% Change = (('table1'[price]/first_price) -1)*100
```

I'm new to PowerBI DAX. Logically the SQL would look like so:

```
SELECT 
date, 
price, 
 ((
     price / 
     ( -- Gets the first price
      SELECT price FROM table1 
      WHERE date IN (SELECT MIN(date) FROM table1 WHERE date BETWEEN '15-APR-2021' AND '30-APR-2021') 
     ) 
 )-1) * 100 as '% change'
FROM table1
WHERE date BETWEEN '15-APR-2021' AND '30-APR-2021'
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to get the first price you can use the following DAX:

```
first_price = CALCULATE(MIN('table1'[price]), FILTER( 'table1', MIN(table1[Date])))
```

As for the % Change:

```
% Change =
var curPrice = 'table1'[price]
var first_price = CALCULATE(MIN('table1'[price]), FILTER( 'table1', MIN(table1[Date])))
return ((curPrice/first_price) - 1) * 100
```